# how to add -Wno-deprecated to make command CFLAG variable to eliminate deprecated warnings

Tags: c, makefile, gcc-warning

Tried:

make all CFLAGS += -D-Wno-deprecated

yields:

make: *** empty variable name. Stop.

Comment: Could you show us your Makefile?

Comment: I can't .. besides the CFLAGS is the GCC variable. I am more interested in the proper make command line syntax since it's obvious I have it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use spaces around `+=` and do not use `-D`: `make all CFLAGS+=-Wno-deprecated`.

Comment: Thanks eric for the correct answer. That solved the problem but introduced a new bizarre issue where I get an immediate missing header file. If I only run make all .. builds ok .. but I get tons of deprecated warning. I guess I can't win  this one.